# Why is cellspacing not working in this table?

Tags: html

```
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td>123
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>345</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>456</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here I want to give a space between rows and columns, but this cell spacing is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xpu2wtw/) and the cellspacing works fine.

Comment: What did you expect the attribute to do, and how did you infer that it does not work?

Answer (score 5):

The markup you provided works as intended, creating a 2px gap between cells. This is made obvious when the cells are given a background color.

That said, the `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` attributes for the `<table>` element [have been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#Attributes) and should not be used.

To create the same style as `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` you can use the CSS properties:

- `padding` on the `<td>`
- [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) on the `<table>`. The [`border-collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) property needs to be left as the default `separate`.

  > The border-spacing CSS property specifies the distance between the
  >   borders of adjacent cells (only for the separated borders model). **This
  >   is equivalent to the cellspacing attribute in presentational HTML**, but
  >   an optional second value can be used to set different horizontal and
  >   vertical spacing.

### Example

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 20px;
  background: #E91E63;
}
td {
  background: #F00;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FCE4EC;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>345</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You set default value, which is 2, try to increase it and you'll see it is working

Answer (score 0):

use the border-collapse: collapse; CSS rule (which has the same effect: no space between table cells). Note that this may not work in older browsers like IE 5 or 6, so if you need to support them you are out of luck.

**< TABLE style="clear: both; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%;" >**